# How do I make Skype use the entire available screen width for my chats?

Tags: skype

It seems silly to waste all that screen real estate.

[image: Mximized Skype window]

You can expand the Skype screen to full width, but the text area maxes-out and does not use it. In lengthy chats it would be useful to be able to see more of the conversation. There is no obvious reason for a hard text width.

Answer (score 44):

As noted in this [bug report](https://jira.skype.com/browse/SCW-1355), you can change the width of the text view by dragging the edges of the input box:

[image]

This way you can make the text view much wider:
[image]

Comment: Not working on mac client.

Comment: @EvgeniPetrov Late reply but for the Mac client you can do the same by dragging the edge of the blue line between the messages and the text input.